# Limit of Riemann integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, limits

The task is to show that
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \int_a^b \lvert f(x + h) - f(x) \rvert\,dx  = 0$$
The function $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$.

I can show this in case $f$ is continuous (then $f$ is uniformly continuous) by bounding the difference $f(x+h)-f(x)$. But in case $f$ is only Riemann integrable I don't know how to show this.

Comment: Hint: f is Riemann integrable on [a,b] iff it is continous almost everywhere on [a,b]

Comment: Yes, but in this case I can's bound difference |f(x+h)-f(x)| uniformly over [a,b] (at points of continuity). How to deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

$f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is Riemann integrable iff for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a partition $P=\{a=t_0<t_1<\cdots < t_n=b\}$ such that
$$
U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\varepsilon
$$
where $$
U(f,P)=\sum_{j=1}^n M_j(t_j-t_{j-1}), \quad U(f,P)=\sum_{j=1}^n m_j(t_j-t_{j-1}),
$$
and $m_j=\inf_{\in[t_{j-1},t_j]}f(x),\,\, M_j=\sup_{x\in[t_{j-1},t_j]}f(x)$.

In particular, if $f_\varepsilon$ is the step-function with the value $M_j$ in $[t_{j_1},t_j)$, then $f_\varepsilon$ is Riemann integrable, and 
$$
\varepsilon>\int_a^b (f_\varepsilon-f)\,dx\ge 0. \tag{1}
$$
If $(\tau_h f)(x)=f(x+h)$, then clearly 
$$
\varepsilon>\int_a^b (\tau_hf_\varepsilon-\tau_hf)\,dx\ge 0, \tag{2}
$$
and 
$$
|h|\sup f\ge\int_a^b (\tau_hf_\varepsilon-f_\varepsilon)\,dx\ge 0, \tag{3}
$$
Combining $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(3)$, and restricting suitably $h$, we obtain that 
$$
\int_a^b |\tau_hf-f|\,dx< 3\varepsilon.
$$